# Fatal error: Allowed memory size ... with Magento on localhost

Tags: magento, localhost

I have been working with Magento on my localhost and everything was fine until i added a new module. now i am getting the following error: 
Fatal error: Allowed memory **size of 268435456** bytes exhausted (**tried to allocate 261900 bytes**) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php

I tried to change the memory_Limit to 512M then it generated the same errors but this time with more memory size:

Fatal error: Allowed memory **size of 536870912** bytes exhausted (**tried to allocate 261900 bytes**) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php

Does anyone have any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put code below to this path:
 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Comment: Just did it and it produced the same error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261900 bytes) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php

Comment: use 1024M instead of 512M: ini_set('memory_limit', 1024M);

Comment: That only does what changing the memory_limit line in the php.ini file did for him. And his system was paying attention to the php.ini file because Magento ran out of memory at the new higher limit when he changed it. It will probably run out with the 1G limit as well, the module seems to have a memory leak. I'd get in touch with the developer that created it at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the extension you've installed has memory leaks in it. If you've payed for it, you should ask for an assistance from the extension developer. Otherwise, you should find the bottleneck place yourself with the help of [xdebug profiler](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) or other similar tool.

At the end, you can just disable the extension.

Comment: Thanks, however i just added a new module manually. There hasn't been any extra extensions.

Comment: by extension, I meant Magento module, sorry for making myself unclear